# Do I need a transit visa in Singapore if I have a valid B1/B2 visa

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, singapore

I'm an Indian national travelling to the U.S. on a B1/B2 visa. I have an 8 hour layover at Singapore during my return leg and would like to get out of the transit area and visit the city. My reading of the [Singapore Immigration site](https://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=96&secid=94) indicates that Indian nationals with a "visa/long-term pass" (=B1/B2?) from the U.S. can transit without a visa for up to 96 hours. A [different page](https://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165) on the site does not say anything about this. Is this reading correct?

Edit: I asked Singapore Airlines and they say the visa is not required if the connecting flight is within 24 hours.

> Transit visa is not required for Indian Nationals as long as your connecting flight is within 24hrs.
>
> We also suggest you to avail free Singapore tour during your transit.
>
> Please click onto below link for more details.
>
> http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/sg/plan-travel/privileges/free-singapore-tour/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [Timatic search at the Emirates site](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=US&DV=United+States&TC=SG&TV=Singapore&h=c0361799c2bf3519b95b4e9f8d2c466cd1c1b33), you can transit without visa.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a maximum transit time of 24 hours.
>
> Nationals of India can also transit, for up to 96 hours without a visa under the Visa Free Transit Facility (VFTF) on either the outbound or return leg of the same journey (but not on both). Leaving the transit area is allowed.
>
> - Holders of a valid single entry visa (or multiple entry visa valid for at least one month) issued by Australia, Canada, Germany, Japan, New Zealand, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom to nationals of India may use the VFTF. After using a single entry visa and the VFTF was not used on the outbound leg of the journey, the VFTF can only be used on the return leg with a direct transit through Singapore from the country that issued the visa to the country of residence (e.g., SYD-SIN-PEK).
>
> Transit passengers holding 2 separate tickets can check in for the connecting flight in the international transit area, except when arriving/departing on a budget carrier. Budget carriers are: Air Asia (AK), Indonesia AirAsia (QZ), Thai AirAsia (FD), Air India Express (IX), Cebu Pacific Air (5J), Firefly (FY), Jetstar (JQ), Jetstar Asia (3K), Jetstar Pacific (BL), Lion Air (JT), Scoot (TZ), Spring Airlines (9C), Tigerair (TR) and VietJet Air (VJ).